# Python 3 output is not printing in Xcode 11

Tags: python, xcode

I've set up Python 3 to run in Xcode 11, and everything is working except the output is not printing to the console. For something simple such as:

> 2+2

I would see "4." I have been able to see results by explicitly calling print(), but is there a way to set it up so that is not required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean in Python, even if you do something, such as `2+2`, you have to call the `print()` function or else the program just executes without an output. You could define another function, like this:

```py
def foo():
  x=2+2
  return x
```